# Decreasing selenium/standalone-chrome memory usage

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm running the `selenium/standalone-chrome:3.141` docker container and am regularly seeing ~4.5GB of RAM usage from the container.  My goal is to be able to support 3-4 concurrent requests to external sites at a time.  To accomplish that, I'm running the container with:

```
NODE_MAX_SESSIONS: '5'
NODE_MAX_INSTANCES: '1'
```

From what I've read, this should give me 1 Chrome instances with a max of 5 sessions.  But with that config, I'm also seeing a lot of these exceptions within my application:

```
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverCurlException
Curl error thrown for http POST to /session with params: {"browserName":"chrome","platform":"ANY","chromeOptions":{"w3c":false,"binary":""}}} Failed to connect to selenium port 4444: Connection refused
```

This suggests to me that it's not able to accept more connections.

How can I run this container in a manner to accept a few concurrent connections/requests to external sites while maintaining as low of a footprint as possible?  I know Chrome is a memory hog, so is it even possible to get it below ~4.5GB memory in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using docker I am assuming it's not important that an actual window/GUI pops up right? Are your webdrivers running in headless mode?
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome
That might save a lot on memory. I also want to note that even when Chrome is being run in headless mode, you can still take screenshots if that's important to you.

Comment: You were right, it wasn't using headless by default.